# Variable for general program cant be used by function or procedure (python)

Tags: python

so yesterday my friend and i work on a problem that we found interested, and we got this trouble: the number Max or Totals cant be used in fmax even though we assigned it as int in the general program, any sugesstion?

```
max = 0
totals = 0
N = 0
C = 0
taken = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
W     = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
def compare(x):
    if x > max:
        max = x
def fmax():
    for i in range(len(taken)):
        #print (max,' ',item)
        if taken[i] ==0 :
            taken[i] =1
            if totals+ W[i] <= C:
                totals += W[i]
                fmax()
                totals -= W[i]
            else:
                compare(totals)
                taken[i] = 0
N = int(input('Enter bulls number: '))
C = int(input('Enter the available weight: '))
for i in range(N):
W[i] = int(input('W[i]='))
totals = 0
fmax()
print (max)
```

Comment: `max` is a builtin python function, you are shadowing it. You should not do that.

Comment: Also, You should probably just put the whole thing into one function with sub-functions or helper functions, make a recursive function, or make a class. You shouldn't work with the globals. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you re-assign to `totals` and `max` inside the functions you have to tell the interpreter that these are global variables and not "new" local ones. Add `global totals` or `global max` in the first line of each relevant function.

Also as @InbarRose commented you better pick a better name for `max` as it shadows a built-in function.